# Application environment variables undefined when application is served by Amplify

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

I have a Vue.js app hosted by AWS Amplify.

In Vue, env vars can be set application-wide by using .env. files.
I currently use such files for development and for production modes, containing different values.
When locally building and serving my application the above works as expected. However, once Amplify deploys my app (in my case I use Amplify's CD feature), these variables are not defined.

I know I can define the same env vars in Amplify, but that would mean I need to manage these values in two places since won't be redeploying while developing. so this seems to be prone to errors (I will need to remember to update the vars on both the application end and amplify console whenever I need to make a change for example).

I wonder if this behavior is expected or is there something I am missing in my setup.

Thanks!

Comment: I was facing the same problem in my React (CRA) app. Turned out I was not pushing my `.env` files to GitHub (this is considered a good practice in some situations). So the `yarn build` on Amplify was not able to inject my env vars. All I had to do to fix this situation was to push the .env files to my GH repo and immediately all my env vars stopped being `undefined` and all values were available in my application JS code as `process.env.REACT_BLAH_XYZ` etc. 

This might be the cause of your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in my React app.
The thing is, you need to have a `.env` file in your app with all the environment variables.

**Why?** — The reason behind that is, it generates static HTML, CSS and JS files. Those files can't access `process` during the runtime.

After adding all the environment variables in Amplify, you have to add one more command in your `build` stage in `App build specification`.

You can refer to [this official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) on how to implement this.

---

If you don't care much about your environment variables, you can use this hack: `printenv`. This will store all the environment variables of your OS and your application in the `.env` file.

My config looks something like this:

```yaml
build:
      commands:
        - 'printenv >> .env'
        - 'npm run build'
```